# Setting the <title> with a function

Tags: php

In my current code I'm setting the title of page by setting variable `$title` and then outputting the variable in `<title>`.

```
<?php
    $title = "My Title";
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    </head>
```

Now, can I make setting and getting the title to be a function? Something like this, but without global variables...

```
<?php
    function set_title( $title ) {
        $GLOBALS[ "title" ] = $title;
    }
    function get_title() {
        return ( isSet( $GLOBALS[ "title" ] ) ) ? htmlspecialchars( $GLOBALS[ "title" ] ) : "";
    }

    set_title( "My Title" );
?>

<html>
    <head>
      <title><?php echo get_title() ?></title>
```

Comment: How can You get information inside an function without using any global variable ,if the title is static you can put it inside of the function.

Comment: @Subhanker I don't know how, that's why I'm asking ;) I was worried that there is no good way to do this, but it's better to ask. And no, the title is not static.

Comment: this might help `get_title(){global $title; return $title }`

Comment: So I should also do this in `set_title()`, right? Like this `function set_title( $my_title ) { global $title; $title = $my_title; }`. But then, if i do something like this: `set_title("foo"); $title="bar";`, the `get_title()` will return `bar`, not `foo` defined by `set_title()`.

Answer (score 0):

**No** Variables declared inside a function are **local** to that function and **can't be accessed outside by any means.**

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2; /* global scope */ 

function test()
{ 
    $b = $a + $b;
    echo $b; /* reference to local scope variable */ 
} 

test();
?>
```

The above could be accessed only through a **global scope** (i.e.)

```
 global $a, $b;

 $b = $a + $b;
```

or

```
$GLOBALS['b'] = $GLOBALS['a'] + $GLOBALS['b'];
```

The same comes to play in your scenario

`$title` with out a global scope `$GLOBALS[ "title" ]` cant be accessed...